# async calls using HttpClient on MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5

I'm playing a little bit with this new technology in .net 4.5, I would like to check the code for this call and how should I control the errors or the response of my async call. 
The call is working perfectly, I need full control of possible errors returned from my service.

this is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TwitterClientMVC.Controllers
{
    public class Tweets
    {
        public Tweet[] results;
    }

    public class Tweet
    {
        [JsonProperty("from_user")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string TweetText { get; set; }
    }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{                                             
    Tweets model = null;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://mywebapiservice");

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweets>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    return View(model.results);            
}
```

Is this the better way to do it? or I'm missing something?
Thanks

I refactor it, is this method async as well?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() 
    {
        Tweets model = null;
        using (HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweets>(
                await httpclient.GetStringAsync("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=pluralsight")
            );
        }
        return View(model.results);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this the better way to do it?

The `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` will throw an exception if the status code returned by your remote service is different than 2xx. So you might want to use the `IsSuccessStatusCode` property instead if you want to handle the error yourself:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{                                             
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://mywebapiservice");

        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweets>(content);
            return View(model.results);            
        }

        // an error occurred => here you could log the content returned by the remote server
        return Content("An error occurred: " + content);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I have another question, if this method is really async, how could I be sure that at the moment of DeserializeObject, the web service has finished?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should use `string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`. This will ensure that by the time the execution reaches the `DeserializeObject` call, the client has finished executing the request and reading the result. My original code was synchronous and blocking because I was calling the `.Result` property on the content that was read. This means that it was also guaranteed that the execution has finished but it was synchronous. It's better to use `await` which is true asynchronous processing.

Comment: thanks, so we need to use it in th GetAsync call and also when we are using ReadAsStringAsync. What about IsSuccessStatusCode? at that moment, are we sure the call was finished?

Comment: Yes, you should use it in both calls, and yes it is guaranteed that by the time you hit the `IsSuccessStatusCode` the call will have completed.

Comment: I did a modification in my first post with a new method, is this method also async?